# How can I fire a Button Click event when PageDown key pressed in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

i write some code in a Button Click event,

> ```
>     private void sabt_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>        some code....
>     }
> ```

i want fire this button action when PageDown" key is pressed in form.

> ```
>      private void myform_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp)
>         {
>            how to fire sabt_btn_Click
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: sabt_btn.PerformClick();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move that code to a separate method, then call that method from both event handlers.